# How to use sshfs on cygwin

Tags: cygwin, sshfs

How to use `sshfs` on `cygwin`? Direct way does not work:

```
$ apt-cyg install sshfs
Installing sshfs
Unable to locate package sshfs
```

Answer (score 7):

You might want to look at https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win

which provides a way to map sshfs drives in windows. If you are using cygwin, you are on windows. Ironically, this port of sshfs to windows uses cygwin dll underneath the covers for POSIX stuff.

After installing sshfs-win, from cygwin bash you should be able to use the windows net use command as per the sshfs-win documentation.

A kludgy method but it would avoid trying to build sshfs under cygwin.

Comment: https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win#unc-syntax and the Windows Credentials manager don't provide a way to use a SSH agent (e.g. Pageant or OpenSSH ssh-agent) or SSH keys.

Answer (score 5):

`sshfs` is not a Cygwin package.  You can check this on https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html.

To use `sshfs`, you would follow the installation instructions on the `sshfs` github page.

https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs/blob/master/README.rst

According to the instructions, you'll also need to install `meson` and `ninja` to build the package, as well as `libfuse` and `Glib`.  These may or may not be in the official packages for Cygwin, you'll have to check, and possibly build those from source as well.

Keep in mind that it could be an exercise in frustration, and it may not be possible.

Comment: ninja, meson are both available as Cygwin packages

Comment: Tried to compile libfuse in cygwin, end up getting "libfuse does not support Windows. Take a look at http://www.secfs.net/winfsp/ instead" https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/f679b6b18654546a1e5fec36f5ec08ae0751e3bb/meson.build#L11  So I guess it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

There is the [`win-sshfs`](https://github.com/Foreveryone-cz/win-sshfs). It is not an equivalent of linux `sshfs`, but it allow to represent remote file system to windows file system. For now install&run proccess looks like the following.

1. Download and install [`docany`](https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokany/releases/tag/v1.0.3) lib v.1.0.3
2. Download and install [`win-sshfs`](https://github.com/Foreveryone-cz/win-sshfs/releases) (for now it version is `1.6.1.13 devel RC5`)
3. Start `C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSshFS\WinSshFS.exe`